# Is it possible to make tabs like this

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm hoping someone with Javascript experience can help me out with these tabs.

Basically, I'm trying to create a tabs that will function in a manner similar to the layout shown in this screen shot. Where the heading is tab #1 followed by a horizontal line and several other tabs...

[image]
The issue I'm having is in making the Heading tag work as a tab.

I've created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pach/rcsxz/1/

If this is possible I'd really appreciate some insight. Thanks!

Comment: So when I click Tab 4, it will take on the heading styles. Will Tab 1 - 3 still be above tab 4?

Comment: Not exactly.  The heading is just tab #1.  Tabs 2 - 5 are their own tabs.  I think the "active" text next to the heading might be confusing you. I just was trying to show that I wanted the content for the Heading a.k.a Tab #1 to be the default content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this. I noticed a few problems that you had. Also, it is good to at least post your html and javascript in your question. You will get more/faster answers if you don't make people click through to a fiddle. This way they can get an idea of the problem quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxz/2/

In your html you use single quotes to enclose your id tags. This is invalid syntax. Use double quotes.

In your jQuery selector you use `$('li', '#id')` is incorrect. This says 'for all list items AND all containers with this id' do the following. You want `$('#id li')` which says 'for all list items in this container' do the following.

Also, not sure if you want title changing, but I did that also.

```
selectTab("tab1");

$("#other-tabs li").click(function() {
    selectTab($(this).attr('id'));
});

function selectTab(id) {
    $("#other-tabs li").show();
    $("#tab-content li").hide();
    $("#" + id + "content").show();
    $('h1').html($('#' + id).html());
    $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and pointers.  I appreciate it! I think my picture might be confusing people.  I'm looking to have the Heading be the first tab - By "active" I was trying to say that I wanted the content for the Heading (aka tab #1) to be the default content when you load the page.

Comment: I see. Then I think your code was almost exactly right. You just needed to fix your jQuery selectors. http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxz/4/

Comment: I've uploaded a new photo that hopefully is a better demonstration.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcsxz/5/ - this more what you are after? You need to attach a click event handler to the h1 tag so that its content can be shown when clicked. I am getting confused?

Comment: Awesome man, that's like exactly what I was trying to do - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure you check the green checkmark as an accepted answer for this one and previous questions. Otherwise you will find that people will stop helping you! You also get +2 rep for accepting an answer so it is good for you too.